# Probability of a number being selected between Min and Max times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have n numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6 ... n)

I randomly select one number from that list (10,000 * n) times. The "expected" number of times that each number will be selected is 10,000.

For the purpose of the problem, assume that Min = 9700, and Max = 10,300

What is the probability that *at least one* of the numbers will be selected more than 10,300 times, or less than 9700?

Comment: _At least one_ of the numbers or _exactly one_ of the numbers selected more than $10300$ or less than $9700$ times?

Comment: ah yes, at least one of the numbers, I'll update the question to be more clear